# Como nao repetir numeros randomicos?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, random

Estou criando um banner rotativo, e para isso uso o random do javascript que sorteia uma posicao no array e exibe, isso ja funciona bem, o problema eh que as vezes sorteia o mesmo numero no random e repete o que esta sendo exibido, quero fazer com que não se repita o sorteio. Estou tentando fazer uma rotina para isso mas depois de um tempo os banners param de serem exibidos e o resultado nao esta legal.

Estou tentando assim.

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.controller('BannerAnuncios', function($scope, $timeout){

    var banners = ["Fernando", "Paiva", "Campos", "Luis", "Gomes"];
    var count = banners.length;
    var lastBanner = 0;

    function rotationBanner(){  
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        if(i != lastBanner){
            $scope.banner = banners[i];
        }else{
            rotationBanner();
        }       

        console.log(lastBanner);
        console.log(i);
        lastBanner = i;
        $timeout(rotationBanner, 5000);
    }

    rotationBanner();

});
```

Comment: Com tão poucas opções de banners, 1 a 5 não aconselharia utilizar randomico unico. até por que chegará uma hora que não terá mais numeros, te aconselho salvar o valor atual e gerar um novo numero randomico, ai voce compara ele, se ele for igual ao atual gera novamente, ate ter um diferente.

Comment: @Highlander sim, mas eu ja faco isso olhe o `else` ele invoca a mesma funcao novamente.

Comment: Faça randomização apenas na distribuição do array e não item a item. usando `.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

Se for só pra exibição você pode usar o filtro `unique`.

Exemplo: `ng-repeat="user in users | unique:'login'"`

Dessa forma ele não irá exibir dois usuários com o mesmo login.

Se quiser fazer um filtro no código recomendo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216066/angularjs-filter-by-unique-attribute-value-and-get-the-filtered-count):

Answer (score 0):

Não sei ao certo como funciona $timeout no angular, se seria o setinterval do js puro, mas vou te dar uma solução que não permite a repetição do número dos banners:

```js
var banners = ["Fernando", "Paiva", "Campos", "Luis", "Gomes"];
var count = banners.length;
var lastBanner = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
  if (i !== lastBanner) {
    document.body.innerHTML = i; // Aqui seus números não serão repetidos.
  }
  lastBanner = i;
}, 1000);
```

Exemplo funcionando no: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/f5w8z9yo/1/)